# ActivatedRoute parameter is not being picked up

Tags: angular

New to Angular

I need to grab a parameter from the end of a URL as follows:

```
http://localhost:4201/projects/46?view=1&pdrId=165
```

I want the value of that pdrId parameter (165) so I can assign it to this.pdr.PDRId.

It made sense to me to get that in the ngOnInit(). The value will never change during this session, so I am attempting to get it with the "snapshot" in this way:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.project = this.data.PdrProject;
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('pdrId'));
    if (id) {
      this.pdr.PDRId = id;
    }
  }
```

When I step through this with the debugger the value is always 0. Clearly, I am doing something wrong but cannot, for the life of me, figure out what it is.

Comment: If you use the browser debugger you can explore what that paramMap looks like at the time ngOnInit is fired. My guess is that it's empty.

Comment: can you try 
      this.route.params.subscribe(data => { console.log(data)
      }) this.route - references ActivatedRoute in constructor

Comment: Sometimes when I use related components, using route data with snapshot causes me problems

Comment: usalin - trying your proposed change now.

Comment: Got it:  let id = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.pdrId;